# Spring Data JPA - JPQL query by given class

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have a specific exercise to do within my university classes homework.
Given entity structure like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Parent {
...some fields...
}

@Entity
public class ChildA extends Parent {
...
}

@Entity
public class ChildB extends Parent {
...
}
```

I have to implement JpaRepository method in ParentRepository or rather JPQL Query to perform update operation on table specified by `Class<? extends Parent>` parameter. Simply, method should update some field but only in a subclass given as a parameter. 
The method structure should be:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {

    void updateInBulk(Class<? extends Parent> clazz, int someParameter);
}
```

I came up with something like this, but it didn't work.

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update :entity e set e.some_field = 'T' where e.other_field > :some_param")
    void updateInBulk(@Param("entity") Class<? extends Parent> clazz, @Param("some_param") int someParam);
}
```

It was just my blind shot, but I could not find any materials which explain how to do stuff like this. 
Does anybody have any suggestion how to solve this task?

Answer (score 1):

You'll wouldn't do this with JPQL, but you'd rather want to write a `Criteria query` for that - which you can add to your JPARepository as well. Something like (you need to adjust this to your needs.)

```
 public void updateInBulk(Class<? extends Parent> clazz, String someParameterName , int someValue) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // create update
    CriteriaUpdate<Order> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(clazz);

    // set the root class
    Root e = update.from(clazz);

    // set update and where clause
    update.set(someParameterName, someValue);
  //  update.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(e.get(someParameterName), oldValue));

    // perform update
    this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
}
```